# Is there a way to get Oracle 18c or 21c Express edition running on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle21c

Dear StackOverflow Community,
i have bought myself a MacBook Pro M1 Pro 2021 and I need for my school a running instance of Oracle 18c or 21c Express Edition.
I have tried creating a VM and running a docker inside of it, but it obviously did not work.
I have also tried running a docker in Docker Desktop directly on my Mac.
I have been using the docker-images provided by oracle, but nothing worked.
Regards,
Daniel

Comment: First, this is not a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow you would be better asking on one of the other StackExchange sites such as http://superuser.com. Second, what does "but nothing works" mean as it does not tell us what you have attempted.

Comment: Instead of a Docker image, why not install Oracle Virtual Box?  There is a download available to run on OS X, downloadable from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).  Install VBox, use it to create a VM, and install Oracle Linux on that VM.  I've built scores of VM's using VBox.   More on it [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/)

Comment: @MT0 
I wasn't aware of that, im sorry. I have never been really active in these communities but thanks for pointing that out! I am going to post the question again on superuser

Comment: @EdStevens Thank you, it was like an option for me but I made the mistake and did not create an Oracle Linux VM but a Ubuntu VM and it obviously did not work. That's why I did not consider continue trying. But I will have a look at it and keep you updated.

Comment: @EdStevens I know the Question has been closed but I just wanted to update you.
I found out that Virtualbox is not available for M1 Macs as it is not supporting ARM architekture.
I found the program UTM for Macs which is specially made for creating VMs on M1 Macs. I just had to download the ARM iso for Oracle linux 8 and create a new vm.

Comment: @Dusto - thanks for the feedback.  I actually have no experience with Macs, but when I saw that VBox was available for OS X, thought that would be it.  Again, with no direct experience, I'd think that the principles of configuring the VM's networking, as described in the cited blog article, would still apply even though some details, particularly terminology, would differ.  Now, having just said that I looked up the user manual to see what it said, and it was pretty sparse on networking details.

Comment: @EdStevens - Don't worry, I myself am new to Mac, but still haven't got it running in any way, because the installation of Oracle Linux 8 fails in UTM so I just gave up and continued using Oracle on my Windows Laptop

Comment: Just to note here for anyone reading: while there are versions of Oracle _Linux_ at this time that run on ARM processors, there is no version of Oracle _Database_ that runs on ARM processors. Oracle Database software only runs on Intel CPUs.

Comment: @Dusto Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @VedantaMohapatra sadly no. I was forced to use a secondary Laptop running Windows. Hopefully oracle will resolve this problem in the near future

Comment: @Dusto Actually I made it run on my Mac M1 Air, after I asked you this. It uses colima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Oracle Database is not supported on ARM processors, only Intel. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1814
2. Oracle Database Docker images are only supported with Oracle Linux 7 or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 as the host OS. See here: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance

> Oracle Database ... is supported for Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7. For more details please see My Oracle
> Support note: Oracle Support for Database Running on Docker (Doc ID
> 2216342.1)

The referenced My Oracle Support Doc ID goes on to say that the database binaries in their Docker image are built specifically for Oracle Linux hosts, and will also work on Red Hat. That's it.

Because Docker provides process level virtualization it still pulls kernel and other OS libraries from the underlying host OS. A Docker image built for Oracle Linux needs an Oracle Linux host; it doesn't bring the Oracle Linux OS with it. Only Oracle Linux or Red Hat Linux are supported for any Oracle database Linux installation, with or without Docker. Ubuntu, Mac OS, Debian, or any other *NIX flavor will not provide predictable reliable results, even if it is hacked into working or the processes appear to work normally ("works" and "supported" are *not* the same thing).

Bottom Line: You won't be able to run an Oracle database on that hardware.

Comment: I know, it is tough out there but some people were able to get it work and I was asking to find a way. I need it for school since we started using oracle which is fine.
But I completely get your points and I have read a lot about it.
Therefore I will continue trying to get it running.
I will keep you updated

Comment: Some people were able to get it to work on older, Intel-based Mac systems, or to use VirtualBox to run an Oracle Linux VM on an Intel-based Mac. There is no version of Oracle that will run on the M1, ARM-based CPU on any operating system.

Comment: Update: I did see where someone claims to have hacked this into working, but the fact remains that it is a *completely* unsupported configuration and would therefore have no value as a legit operating platform - even for development. Why would you develop to a deployment target that cannot be relied on and that no one will ever use?

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/) and utilize their always free offerings.
You can create an autonomous database in matter of minutes and you can use it f o r e v e r  free of charge.

Note! You will have to provide a credit card when signing up. This is for identification purposes, but as long as you do not upgrade the account to `paid`, your card will not be charged. The first 30 days, you can build your own datacenter with the cloud credits granted.

```
# spin up a database from the command-line
oci db autonomous-database create \
  --compartment-id $C \
  --is-free-tier TRUE \
  --display-name DEMODB \
  --db-name DEMODB \
  --admin-password "${PASSWORD}" \
  --cpu-core-count 1 \
  --data-storage-size-in-tbs 1 \
  --db-workload "${WORKLOAD}" \
  --db-version 21c \
  --license-model LICENSE_INCLUDED \
  --freeform-tags '{"Version": "21c"}'
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I knew about Oracle Cloud and I will try this one out if the option from @EdStevens does not work or fails.